# NameError: name 'uinput' is not defined error in Python

Tags: python, nameerror

I'm trying to make a simple CLI app for todo-lists. What's happening here? Is it because I'm referring to a variable that's inside a function?

I've tried putting "global" behind uinput, but that said that the "=" was not valid syntax or something along those lines. Not quite sure why, I've also tried looking around for a while on google and couldn't find anything, sorry if it is obvious.

```
userlist = []

 def maininput():
     uinput = input("What would you like to add to your list?")
     userlist.append(uinput)
     for i in userlist:
         print(userlist)
         break


 while uinput != "exit":
     maininput()
```

What I would like that happened was that "uinput" could be recognized to do the while statement

Comment: you need to make uinput a global, if you wanna use it like that.!

Comment: Unlike in many other languages, `global uinput` needs to be on a line by itself.

Comment: ...*however*, having functions modify globals is generally considered bad design. Consider doing something else -- say, having `maininput()` itself check for `exit`, or having it `return uinput` when it exits so the caller can check the return value without depending on global scope (`while mainput() != "exit": pass`).

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your `uinput` in your function globally in a such way:

```py
global uinput
uinput = input("...")
```

In global scope(before declraring a function) you should specify a value for `uinput`

```py
uinput = input("...")
```

Intead of `...` you should fill in your input prompt

Answer (score 0):

Use a `while True` loop to break your list inside `maininput`, instead of using a global like below. Also you can print the list directly using `print(userlist)`, instead of a for loop

```
userlist = []
def maininput():
    while True:
        uinput = input("What would you like to add to your list? Type exit to stop>>")
        #Exit the loop when you type exit
        if uinput == "exit":
            break
        #Else append to list and print it
        userlist.append(uinput)
        print(userlist)

#Call the main function
maininput()
```

The outputs will look like

```
What would you like to add to your list? Type exit to stop>>a
['a']
What would you like to add to your list? Type exit to stop>>b
['a', 'b']
What would you like to add to your list? Type exit to stop>>c
['a', 'b', 'c']
What would you like to add to your list? Type exit to stop>>d
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
What would you like to add to your list? Type exit to stop>>exit
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes, it's because you are referring to a name that's defined inside a function. You are now aware of a concept called "scoping."

Inside any Python function, names are resolved by looking in three places in order:

1. The function call's local namespace, created when the function
   is called and destroyed when it returns or otherwise exits;
2. The module's global namespace, which is where top-level classes and
   functions are defined;
3. The *built-in* namespace, which contains Python's pre-defined values like
   `None`, `Exception` - all the names that are a part of the Python language.

Outside a function, statements (sometimes referred to as top-level statements) the local and global namespaces are the same.

When the interpreter compiles a function call, any names that are bound (by assigning them a value, or defining a nested class or function) are assumed to be local to that call. This is why the top-level statements couldn't reference `uinput`.

Other answers have given you some insight into a better looping structure. I'd encourage you, as your skill level grows, to investigate modules like [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) and [`shelve`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html) or even `dbm`, which will let your to-do lists stay alive between program runs.

Answer (score 0):

You place the last input word in `userlist`, and it's easy to access `userlist` contents from the main loop because ① `userlist` is initialized in the main ② when the function search for a list to which append the user's input it finds `userlist` in the outer scope and ③ `userlist` is a mutable object, whose changes are visible from every point in its scope.

```
userlist = []

def ask():
    new = input('...')
    userlist.append(new)
    if new == 'exit' : return
    print('List contains', ', '.join(s for s in userlist))

while userlist[-1:] != ['exit']:
    ask()
```

(we write the test like this: `userlist[-1:] != ['exit']` because at the first pass `userlist` is empty and indexing it, rather than extracting a slice, would raise an error).

Of course this is BAD PRACTICE because we introduce a strong coupling between the main and the function, it's much better to pass explicitly the list in the argument list:

```
userlist = []

def update_list(a_list):
    new = input('...')
    a_list.append(new)
    if new == 'exit' : return
    print('List contains', ', '.join(s for s in a_list))

while userlist[-1:] != ['exit']:
    update_list(userlist)
```